# Android: clicking issue of overlapping imageViews with transparent background

Tags: android, imageview, overlapping

I have two clickable imageViews that partially overlap each other, let's say a big one is at the bottom as base and the small one is on the top right corner of it. Sample view: [this](http://draw.to/DPxEHf). The black circle is where I have problem getting big image's listener.

The problem is, the transparent area is invisible but still there, lead to onTouch action is not so "accurate". E.g. Clicking on the overlapping area, where small image is transparent and big isn't, the small image will be detected, but what I want is to get the big image detected.

Using onTouchListener to catch the colour to make transparent areas not clickable won't help neither.

How can I solve this please?

```
ImageView big, small;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seventh);

    big = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBig);
    small = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSmall);

    big.setOnTouchListener(this);
    small.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageViewBig:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Big", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.imageViewSmall:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Small", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "none", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.gamification.gamificationpagestudy.ProgressBar.SeventhActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBig"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/germany" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewBig"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewBig"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewBig"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/brazil" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you have a small image which overlaps a bigger image and when you click on the small image area you want to call the big image click listener?

Comment: What you can do is to fix the problem is that , if you dont have anything to perform on SMALL image. write a code of what you want to perform on  BIGGER image.

Comment: @Dreo yes, when i click on the transparent area of small image, i want it to be really transparent and just "pass through" the small image to get the big image click listener.

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi unfortunately I need both imageViews to perform something

Comment: Set click listeners for the big image, when small image is touched, call onclick listener of the big image + other code you have to run.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the layout?

Comment: @Dreo pls refer this [sample](http://draw.to/DPxEHf) for small red image and big blue image positions, black circle is where I have problem getting the big image onclick listener. (sorry stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post an image yet)

Comment: k, now it's clear. I have never done this but i can give you a suggestion. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick  in your big image. Then you have to get coordinates of the touched area in the red image. If it's in the bottom-left, call the onClick method of the big image.

Comment: I will have 2 big base imageViews, one located at bottom left corner of the small image, another one at bottom right corner.

Comment: @Dreo thanks for your suggestion, I will try and get back here soonest as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dreo for his suggestion :D

Continue with onTouchListner to get transparent area, get as well the touched View's mid point to check whether bottom left or right area is touched, then do your action, in my case bottom left corner is my GridView's item at position 0, and bottom right corner is item at position 1:

```
if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT) {

    int touchX = (int) event.getX();
    int touchY = (int) event.getY();
    int middle_width = v.getWidth()/2;
    int middle_height = v.getHeight()/2;

    if (touchX < middle_width && touchY > middle_height) // bottom left
       Toast.makeText(GamificationMainActivity.this, gvAdapter.getItem(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else if (touchX > middle_width && touchY > middle_height) // bottom right
       Toast.makeText(GamificationMainActivity.this, gvAdapter.getItem(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      return true;

   } else { //... }
```